# How to tell if an HTTP response terminates in C

Tags: http, browser, https, mbed

I'm implementing a minimum HTTPS layer for my embedded project where I'm using [mbedTLS for TLS](http://tls.mbed.org/) and hard-coding HTTP headers to talk with HTTPS servers.

It works fine with normal websites. But so far my implementation detects the end of HTTPS response by checking if the last byte read is `\n`.

```
if( ret > 0 && output[len-1] == '\n' )
{
    ret = 0;
    output[len] = 0;
    break;
}
```

This, however, is not always working for obvious reason. I tried `openssl s_client`, and it behaves the same - if an HTTP response terminates with `\n`, then `s_client` returns immediately after fetching all data. Otherwise it blocks forever, waiting for more data.

An real browser seems to be able to handle this properly. Is there anything I can do beyond setting a timeout?

Answer (score 0):

> How to tell if an HTTP response terminates in C... 
> But so far my implementation detects the end of HTTPS response by checking if the last byte read is `\n`... 
> This, however, is not always working for obvious reason...

HTTP calls out `\r\n`, and *not* `\n`. See [RFC 2616, Hypertext Transfer Protocol - HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and page 15:

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all
> protocol elements except the entity-body (see appendix 19.3 for
> tolerant applications). The end-of-line marker within an entity-body
> is defined by its associated media type, as described in section 3.7.
>
> CRLF = CR LF

Now, what various servers send is a whole different ballgame. There will be duplicate  end-of-line markers, missing  end-of-line markers, and incorrect  end-of-line markers. Its the wild, wild west.

You might want to look at a reference implementation of a HTTP parser. If so, check out [libevent](http://libevent.org/) or [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/dev/source.html)'s parsers and how they maintain their state machine.